# Lambda Function with IF condition in Python Pandas DataFrame behaves weirdly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a CSV File with records (rows) of sales made in a store. Each record contains information about the client and the purchase done in the store (columns).

After opening my File as a DataFrame named `sales`, I calculate the mean of one the columns (`Amount_Sales`), and I want to add a new column (`Type_of_Sales`) according to the following rule: If the number is lower than the mean of `Amount_Sales`, then assign the string ‘Low’, and if the value is higher than the mean, assign the string 'High'.

I tried to use a lambda function:

```
sales['Type_of_Sales'] = sales['Amount_Sales'].apply(lambda x: 'Low' if x < sales.Amount_Sales.mean() else 'High')
```

and it doesn't work (the console stops working... looks like it is 'locked' in an infinite loop').

But if I calculate the mean **beforehand**, assign it to a variable, and then I use it in the lambda function definition, it works.

```
sales_mean = sales.Amount_Sales.mean()
sales['Type_of_Sales'] = sales['Amount_Sales'].apply(lambda x: 'Low' if x < sales_mean else 'High')
```

Does anyone knows why one of the codes is working and not the other?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it could be because, in the first approach, you are calculating the mean of Amount_Sales for every iteration (each row of the new column), which is computationally expensive, which is probably why your console is crashing.

But in the second approach you are only calculating the mean only once and reusing the calculated value.

This explanation is considering the dataset you are working with is reasonably large.
Again, I'm not entirely sure if this is the cause.

Comment: I tested your suggestion by reducing the size of my original dataframe to 10 rows and... it worked!! You were right!! Thank you so much!!!